# How to get the active #comment-cid when a comment permalink is clicked?

Tags: 7, comments, uri

I am trying to get the comments on my website to change color when they are active. More specifically, I am looking to do something very similar to what StackExchange sites do when you click on a notification in your inbox (like [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/125258/c2-a2b2-2ab-cosc-getting-a-different-answer-than-creating-a-third-trian/125263#125263)). So what I initially tried to do, was to wrap the comment class in another div class called `comment_active` using an `if` statement to see whether the current page url contained the string "#comment-". (being that the permalink for a comment is `/node/nid#comment-cid` I am trying to get drupal to know what the current cid is) I am having some problems figuring out how to do this. Is placing, for example `#comment-1` even part of the url? or does it just bring you to the part of the page that contains that element id? is there a way that I can have the comment.tpl.php know whether a comment is active? Or should I be doing it some other way entirely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add a custom javascript file to in theme.info file

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    //get the current path
    var pathname = window.location.hash;
    jQuery(pathname).next().addClass('active-comment');
    //here add your custom animation
    jQuery('.active-comment').fadeOut().fadeIn().fadeOut().fadeIn().fadeOut().fadeIn().fadeOut().fadeIn().fadeOut().fadeIn().fadeOut().fadeIn().fadeOut().fadeIn().fadeOut().fadeIn();

});
```

here is a plugin to animate the background color of the wrapper :[here](http://www.bitstorm.org/jquery/color-animation/)

Hope this will Help You

Comment: I'm confused as to what this does. does this add the class `active_comment` to the `.comment_class`? or does this create a class for every element with an `id`?

Comment: I forgot to add .next() , because the structure of drupal comment is <a href='#idofcomment'></a><div class="wrapperofcomment"></div>, now the code above will add the class to the comment wrapper instead of adding it to the <a> ,

Comment: I added a comments.js file with that code, and pointed to it in the theme.info file, but it doesn't seem to working. Is there something else I'm supposed to be doing, I'm new to jquery with drupal. Also, when I look up online on how to use jquery with drupal,other people seem to be using `JQuery();` instead of `$()`. Does that make a difference hear at all. I'm using drupal 7.12

Comment: Out of curiosity, would there also be a way to do this using php?

Comment: I've updated my code snippets , and it's a tested code and working for me

Comment: The `addClass` part worked great, but I ended up using 
`@keyframes activecomment
{
from {background: red;}
to {background: #535B6B;}
}`
in the css for the animation